# Is necessary digitally sign a document more than once?

Tags: digital-signature

I usually sign a lot of documents digitally to send over email, and usually I just sign the document digitally once.

But recently I've been told that I need to paste a digital sign in every place I was going to sign the document with my own hand writing, some documents I make can have around 30 or 40 places that I will sign with my handwritten sign, mostly because they include blueprints and every blueprint needs a sign, and this can become very tedious.

My doubt is if there is really a difference to sign the document digitally more than once, or if the other signs are just redundant.

Comment: "I have been told I need to paste a digital sign in every place I was going to sign the document with my own hand writing" - Sounds like you were told this was required, which means, its required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what kind of "signature" is needed.

If all you need is to "seal" the document then only one signature is required. The cryptographic signature will allow people to validate that the contents of the file have not been changed since your signature was applied. If the contents change then the signature should be invalidated and the document will need to be re-signed. This is the first use case of a digital signature.

On the other hand, signing in multiple locations within the document can provide an audit trail showing that you have gone through all the necessary steps. The timestamps will show whether you have taken the time to do the step properly and can also show if someone has cross-checked the document. Each successive signature revalidates the contents of the document (including signatures) again and creates a chain of authorisations. No one can go back to edit an earlier signature or the original contents without breaking the entire chain and forcing the process to be completed **fully** again.

Largely though it depends on your workflow. Do you need cross checking or to validate each stage as complete? Or do you just want a big rubber stamp that says "DONE" stamped on your document?

If your company has a policy on how to go about this then you should be following that policy.